Create P12 with OpenSSL 3 and RC2-40-CBC
I am using OpenSSL 3.2.1 that comes with Fedora 40. I need to create a P12 that is ciphered with RC2-40-CBC for a legacy application. Is it possible?
I can't find the option to do it with openssl 3
Can someone help me?
Thanks

Have you tried searching, such as this and this?

Or man openssl-pkcs12 | less +/RC2 +n +6k (i.e. search for second occurrence and scroll up)

Thanks! you also need to user -legacy
so
-keypbe PBE-SHA1-RC2-40 -legacy
or
-legacy will also do it (I guess RC2-40-CBC is the default in legacy)
